# Apache Drill startup NoSuchMethod exception (Jackson JsonFactory) using drillbit.sh

Tags: hadoop, exception, jackson, apache-drill

I have installed Apache Drill 0.8.0 on a Hadoop 2.7.0 cluster with ZooKeeper 3.4.9. On slave machines in the cluster Drill starts up well. But on the master node, it throws the following error (in drillbit.out)

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonFactory.requiresPropertyOrdering()Z
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.<init>(ObjectMapper.java:458)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.<init>(ObjectMapper.java:379)
    at org.apache.drill.common.config.DrillConfig.<init>(DrillConfig.java:61)
    at org.apache.drill.common.config.DrillConfig.create(DrillConfig.java:166)
    at org.apache.drill.common.config.DrillConfig.create(DrillConfig.java:139)
    at org.apache.drill.common.config.DrillConfig.create(DrillConfig.java:127)
    at org.apache.drill.exec.server.Drillbit.start(Drillbit.java:66)
    at org.apache.drill.exec.server.Drillbit.main(Drillbit.java:166)
```

All other Hadoop components are running fine. The master node has Hive 2 installed which the slave nodes do not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I restarted all my images and made sure that the PATH variable was not stacking up with unnecessary stuffs and CLASSPATH was clean (I believe Hive and Derby installation did mess it up a bit).

Drill is now started on the master machine without any problem.